# Установка сервера на удаленную машину Java

Tags: java, spring, netty

В рамках обучения приобрел подписку на kamatera.com. Поставил туда ubuntu 18 и запустил простейшее spring boot приложение на netty. В итоге я могу обращаться к нему в таком формате:
http://123.12.12.123:8080/api/ping.

Теперь мне бы хотелось убрать порт из url, чтобы я мог делать запросы примерно так: http://my_server.(com|ru)/api/ping.

Что мне нужно для этого сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. сменить порт в [конфигурации spring boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port) на дефолтный для http (т.е. на `80`);
2. запустить ваше Spring Boot приложение из-под `root`, т.к. для прослушивания порта ниже `1024` (в вашем случае, `80`) в Linux требуются права пользователя `root` (пользователя с uid = 0).

Comment: Ещё, по идее, можно через nginx/apache пробрасывать, хотя, наверное, их тоже придётся тогда под рутом запускать, в чём не уверен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да все верно, но я так понял, что у коллеги всего один сервер, поэтому вариант с балансером и/или reverse proxy предлагать не стал, т.к. там пришлось бы решать схожые проблемы (но при этом master процесс того же nginx можно стартануть как демон, а они стартуются из-под root'а, а затем уже все slave процессы стартуются с понижением привелегий до другого пользователя/группы за счет конфигурации файла /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service).